# Use JTable in another class

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The code below takes data from a text file delimited by "|" and displays it in a `JTable`. When I run it on the `JFrame` itself it does work. However I cannot figure out how to move it to another class for itself and make it become a method such as `public void viewUser(){}`, then call it from the frame on click of a button.

```
public void viewUser(){
    File file = new File("user.dat");
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        Object[] lines = br.lines().toArray();

        for (Object line : lines) {
            String[] row = line.toString().split("\\|");
            model.addRow(row);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserManagement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: *"Considering the gui already contains a jTable with Column names"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data in a `String`, to replace the external file - it's irrelevant to the immediate problem.

Comment: Have `viewUser` return the model. Get the model from the `JFrame`s class and use it in a `JTable`   :  `new JTable(model)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this wrong conceptually: a model by itself is meaningless. It needs to be *connected* to a table in order to show its content.

The code you are showing is creating and filling a new table model. Then that model and all the information is thrown away. Reading data into an object is pointless, when that object isn't made available for further usage!

You might simply change the return type from void to DefaultTableModel and return the model object in the end. And then you can use that pre-filled model for any JTable!

Comment: I get what you mean but I am having trouble with this part         `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();` How do I change this to build a model? Considering the gui already contains a jTable with Column names

Comment: I actually overlooked that part. Guess I have to rework my answer. But that might take a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Run this [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see if it mocks what you want to do:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TablePane extends JPanel {

    private final JTable table;

    public TablePane() {

        super(new GridLayout(1,0));
        String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Age" };

        Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", new Integer(35)},
                {"John", new Integer(63)},
                {"Sue", new Integer(28)},
                {"Joe", new Integer(70)}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    void refresh() {
        new Updater(table).getNewData();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TablePane tablePane = new TablePane();
        frame.add(tablePane);
        JButton button = new JButton("Change data");
        button.addActionListener(e -> tablePane.refresh());
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Updater {

    private DefaultTableModel model;

    Object[][] testData = {
            {"Bon", new Integer(15)},
            {"Anna", new Integer(31)},
            {"Dan", new Integer(82)},
            {"Jane", new Integer(20)},
    };

    public Updater(JTable table) {
         model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    }

    void getNewData(){
        //if you want to clear data : model.getDataVector().clear();
        for (Object[] row : testData) {
            model.addRow(row);
        }
    }
}
```

As commented by Andrew Thomson mcve with hard coded data is essential.